# Redux Thunk Middleware not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-thunk

I am implementing a basic login using Redux. When I created my store I did the following:

```
const store = createStore(
    reducers,
    applyMiddleware(thunk)
);
```

Then in my actions I mapped to props the handler for login...

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch, ownProps) => {
    return {
        loginRoute: (username,password) => {
            dispatch(loginRoute(username,password));
        },
        dispatch
    }
};
```

The action is then dispatched on submit...

```
this.props.loginRoute(username.value,password.value);
```

The login route function looks like this .....

```
export function loginRoute(username, password){
    return axios({
      method: 'post',
      url: '/login',
      data: {
        'username': username,
        'password': password
      }
    }).then((response)=>{
        if(response.data === "no username in database"){
          // send action to update state, no username in database
          return{
            type: "ERROR",
            response
          };
        }else if(response.data ==="incorrect password"){
          return{
            type: "ERROR",
            response
          };
        }else{
          return{ 
            type: 'LOGIN',
            data:response 
          };      
        }
    }).catch((error)=>{

      return{
        type: "ERROR",
        response: error
      };
    });
}
```

However, with all of this I get the error Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions.

Any ideas as to why? I am using the thunk middleware and the logic seems to be correct.

Comment: try to check your response of login route with reducer state is matching

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to return a function from your action creator:

```
export function loginRoute(username, password) {
    return function(dispatch, getState) {
        axios({...}).then((response) => {
            ...
            dispatch({type: 'LOGIN', data: response})
        }
    }
}
```

You might use the shorthand syntax for this:

```
export const loginRoute = (username, password) => (dispatch, getState) => {
    ...
}
```

Alternatively, there is another middleware that you can use, which should make it possible to implement exactly like you did above, https://github.com/acdlite/redux-promise

Comment: Interesting. I got it working with your input but I am wondering if this is the best way to implement this kind of logic. Thank You!